# Can assign a new domain to a site in a multisite?

Tags: multisite, domain

We set up a multisite for a client so they could choose a style. The URLs are:

- `http://client.ourdomain.com/project/style1/`
- `http://client.ourdomain.com/project/style2/`
- `http://client.ourdomain.com/project/style3/`

Client chose style2 and purchased domain `clientdomain.com`

Any way to make `clientdomain.com` the new URL for `http://client.ourdomain.com/project/style2/` without re-installing Wordpress and transferring everything, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Network Admin screen of the site, then Sites, then Edit the site. Put the new URL in the various locations.

**Added**

When you Edit the site, select the Settings tab. That will allow you to change the Home and Site URL values (which writes to the wp-options for that site). There may also be several other places to change the URL for other options settings by plugins or themes.

You may need to do a Search/Replace (I like the 'Better Search and Replace' plugin) to change URLs for media for that site. And a backup of the databases is always a good idea before changing.

Comment: That doesn't work. Can't change the base domain.

Comment: See added info in my answer.